# Syntax error file operation

Tags: python, file

I am new to python/repy. I am trying to determine if a string exist in list of files in current directory. This is my code.

```
def checkString(filename, string):
input = file(filename) # read only will be default file permission
found = false
searchString = string
for line in input:
    if searchString in line:
        found = true
    break

if callfunc == 'initialize':
    print listdir() #this will print list of files

for files in listdir():
    checkString(files,"hello")

if found:
    print "String found"
else:
    print "String not found"
```

What is the error and how can i solve it?

I am running this in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
Full debugging traceback:
"repy.py", line 448, in <module>
"repy.py", line 179, in main
"/home/hardik_darji/REPY/seattle/seattle_repy/virtual_namespace.py", line 78, in     __init__
```

User traceback:

```
Exception (with type 'exceptions.ValueError'): Code failed safety check! Error: ("<type 'exceptions.IndentationError'> expected an indented block (line 13)",)
```

Comment: "What is the error" - you're supposed to tell us that.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths. Just posted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here:

1. You are missing colons at the end of your for-loops, your if-statements, and your else-statement.
2. You misspelled `False` and `True` (Python is case-sensitive remember).
3. Your indentation is off (not sure if this is just a SO formatting error though).
4. Though it won't cause a `SyntaxError`, you need to put `break` one level deeper to get the script to work properly.
5. You need to close the file by doing `input.close()`.

Your code should be:

```
def checkString(filename, string):
    input = file(filename) # read only will be default file permission
    found = False
    searchString = string
    for line in input:
        if searchString in line:
            found = True
            break

    if callfunc == 'initialize':
        print listdir() #this will print list of files
        print "\n"

    for files in listdir():
        checkString(files,"hello")

    if found:
        print "String found"
    else:
        print "String not found"
    input.close()
```

Also, I would recommend that you do not name a variable `input`--it overshadows the built-in.

Finally, you should look into the [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement to work with files.  `with` is a context manager that will auto-close the file for you.

Comment: @iCodez, thank you for solution. But it prints nothing on terminal outout. why so ?

Comment: I did changes as shown. Thank you. But it prints nothing in command line. why so ?

Comment: He could close the file with `file.close` or with a `with` statement, which is almost always a better choice.

Comment: @Hardik are you calling the function?

Comment: @Hardik - Hmm, I don't really know.  At the very least it should print `"String not found"`.  Did you call the function right?

Comment: @iCodez. I am running locally in seattle repy by command 
python repy.py restrictions.test os1.repy

Comment: Will this code ever reach the `if found:` check?  It calls itself recursively before that (at least if `listdir()` is nonempty), no?

Comment: @iCodez, I evenn tried

  sudo python /home/hardik_darji/REPY/seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py /home/hardik_darji/REPY/seattle/seattle_repy/restrictions.test os1.repy

with another folder which contains only text files (if some file access errors)

Comment: @Hardik - I'm sorry, but I don't know what could be the problem.  The fact that you are seeing nothing is strange to me.  You should at least see `"String not found"` or, as DSM stated, a `RuntimeError` caused by an infinite recursive loop.  Perhaps you should ask a new question (after all, the topic of this one was syntax errors, which my code fixes).

Comment: @iCodez: it looks like we merely guessed wrong about how the OP's code was indented.  In retrospect, I think the function should end with a `return found` after the first `for` loop.  (The OP opened up a separate question which made this clear.)